# ClientValidation In Form not showing When I Send Id Variable To Jquery in YII

Tags: yii

I Need Help in Yii, i get problem in my form, the problem is if i put id in textfield then client validation not showing for that field but another field no problem. This is my code in form

```
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'latar_belakang'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'latar_belakang',array('id' => 'latarbelakang','class' => 'input-block-level')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'latar_belakang'); ?>

        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'rumusan_masalah'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'rumusan_masalah',array('id' => 'rumusanmasalah','class' => 'input-block-level')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'rumusan_masalah'); ?>
    </div>
```

for your knows i use id in textfield for calculaten field with jquery which i put in form . this is my jquery code in form

```
 Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');

        Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('totalValues',"
                function totalValues()
                {
                    var lb =    $('#latarbelakang').val() ;
                    var rm =    $('#rumusanmasalah').val();
                    var tot  = parseInt(lb) + parseInt(rm);
                $('#nilaiakhir').val( tot );
                }
        ", CClientScript::POS_HEAD);

        Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('changeTotals', "      
                $('#latarbelakang').change( function(){ totalValues(); } );
                $('#rumusanmasalah').change( function(){ totalValues();} );
        ", CClientScript::POS_END);
```

What i must do ? for solving this problem ?.
Thanks B4..

Answer (score 0):

By default Yii generates ids of fields dynamically using model name and field name.

For example for 'password' field of 'User' model the id would be 'User_password'

You can inspect a field(to which you have not given your custom id) with firebug and see the auto generated id. also yii maps error messages with those auto generated ids in response. that is why your error messages are not showing.

what you can do is to try to call that js function with yii generated id.

Comment: thanks much for your  answer, but i have solved it with change  the id with class and in jquery i change $('#latarbelakang').val() with $('input.latarbelakang').val(). Now ClientValidation running normaly